# Is there a way for a hacker to abuse my refresh token?

Tags: reactjs, security, cookies, oauth-2.0, jwt

Hi guys I'm recently building a web app, which is basically a shopping site. Security is one of my major concerns. I'm gonna use JWTs (access token & refresh token).

I'm gonna implement it this way: the server will return both access token and refresh token to a logged in user. And for the front end, I'm using React, so I'm gonna save the access token(short lived) in memory(like React context). I'm thinking about store the refresh token(long lived) in cookie, so I'm wondering is there a way for a hacker to extract the cookie and then use it on some clients like Postman and send requests to get access token and write some Javascript to get the access token?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe think of keeping both of these tokens in memory? If you want your user to be still logged in when they come back to your application, you can rely on an SSO session that will log them in seamlessly, instead of using a refresh token in the background.

Have a look at these [SPA security best practices](https://curity.io/resources/learn/spa-best-practices/). Also I would recommend not to use JWTs as access and refresh tokens, so that no one can read the data that is kept in your JWTs. You can use Token Introspection in your APIs or implement a [Phantom Token Approach](https://curity.io/resources/learn/phantom-token-pattern/) instead.

Have a look also at [this document by W3C](https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-post-spectre-webdev/#tldr) which gives some guidelines on security settings you can use for your application.

Answer (score 0):

Your question does not sound stupid at all! It is a great question. There is a way for a hacker to extract the cookie yes. Cookie stealing is a known security issue.

However the way to stop this issue is by enabling CORS that blocks any cross origin API manipulation. By doing this you create a whitelist enabling your web app's URL.

I would recommend disabling this on your development server to enable localhost for faster development, and then enabling it on production.

Here is some starting documentation on CORS: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Happy coding!